# AlarmManager not firing off consistently

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have gone through all of the posts on this subject and I feel I have my code as close as possible to the solutions posted. But my alarmanager is not kicking off consistently. If the time is in the past, it has no problems and the event is logged in my log file. It never goes off for events the next day. Sometimes for events a few hours away in the current day.

Here is the code that creates the AlarmManager:

```
public void createNotifications(ArrayList alertList){


   ResortActivity activity;

   int arryLen = alertList.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < arryLen; ++i){

     activity = (ResortActivity) alertList.get(i);
     if (activity.getActAlert().equals("Y")){
         //Loop through array list checking if alert set to Y if so create alert

         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);


         // Every scheduled intent needs a different ID, else it is just executed once

         int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
         // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date

         //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNotifier.class);
         //Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNotifier.class);
         //TODO check if object can be passed and pass ResortActivity
         intent.putExtra ("Alert_ID", activity.getActId());
         // Prepare the pending intent

         Integer actIntID = new Integer(activity.getActId());

         id = actIntID.intValue();

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         // Register the alert in the system. You have the option to define if the device has to wake up on the alert or not

         Calendar actCal = activity.getCalendar();

         System.out.println("Activity Date : "
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +"/"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "  "
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                 + ":"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                 + ":"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

         System.out.println(actCal.toString());
         actCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -15);
         System.out.println(actCal.toString());

         System.out.println("After 15 min : "
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +"/"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "  "
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                 + ":"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                 + ":"
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
                 + actCal.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

         //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, activity.getCalendar().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, actCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
     }//end if for alert = "Y"
   }

}//createNotifications
```

Here is the class the receives the Alarm

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "ResortPlanner");

     //Acquire the lock
     wl.acquire();

    System.out.println("here in onReceive");
    ResortActivity activity = null;
    final GlobalVariables globalVariables = (GlobalVariables) context.getApplicationContext();

    int actID;

    actID = new Integer(intent.getStringExtra("Alert_ID")).intValue();


    Logger tlogger = new Logger();
    tlogger.setLogFilename(globalVariables.getLogFilename());
    tlogger.setLogClass("ActivityNotifier");
    tlogger.setLogMsg("ID: " + actID);
    tlogger.setLogProcedure("Activity Notifier");
    tlogger.setLogType("I");
    tlogger.logMessage();           

    ActivitiesReader actReader = new ActivitiesReader(globalVariables.getActAlertFullName());
    try{
        activity = actReader.getActivity(actID);
    }catch (ResortAppsException e){         
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        logger.setLogFilename(globalVariables.getLogFilename());
        logger.setLogClass(e.getErrClass());
        logger.setLogMsg(e.getErrMsg());
        logger.setLogProcedure(e.getErrProcedure());
        logger.setLogType("E");
        logger.logMessage();            

        logger = new Logger();
        logger.setLogFilename(globalVariables.getLogFilename());
        logger.setLogClass("ActivityNotifier");
        logger.setLogMsg("Unable to create notified due to previous error.");
        logger.setLogProcedure("onReceive");
        logger.setLogType("E");
        logger.logMessage();            

    }


     // Request the notification manager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTxtStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();          
                bigTxtStyle.bigText(activity.getActTime() + " " + activity.getActDescr());               
                bigTxtStyle.setBigContentTitle("Activity Reminder");



     NotificationCompat.Builder noteBuild = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle("Activity Reminder")
     .setContentText(activity.getActTime() + " " + activity.getActDescr())
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE + Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
     .setStyle(bigTxtStyle);


     // Fire the notification
     Notification notify = noteBuild.build();
     notificationManager.notify(actID, notify);
     //notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

     wl.release();

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to confirm that the schedule is what you think it is. Also, if your `onReceive()` code is doing disk or network I/O -- which the code suggests may be the case -- you need to move that out of `onReceive()`, which is called on the main application thread. Rather than rolling your own `WakeLock` logic, use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` coupled with an `IntentService`, or use a regular `BroadcastReceiver` coupled with my `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to android and using the adb really helped. I removed all of the extra stuff in the onReceive and it is working great.